# Cannot find main class on Linux - Classpath issue

Tags: java, linux, classpath, java-7, bash

I am having some trouble running a few jar's on a linux box. Basically, I am getting an error saying it cannot find the main class of my main jar. The class is defenetly present so it must be a classpath issue.
I am not great with linux, so I am looking for some advice as to where I might be missing something.

First off, I am setting the classpath in the users bash_profile; adding all the jar's required, seperated by a : delimeter. I then export the classpath.

Then, in the shell (ksh) script I use to invoke the main jar, I also st the classpath and call it in the command using -cp

so it looks like:

```
TEST_ROOTDIR = /Test/app
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:${TEST_ROOTDIR}/lib/myjar.jar
...
export CLASSPATH

CMD_STRING="java -Xms200m -Xmx200m -XX:MaxPermSize=200m -verbose -cp $CLASSPATH"
CMD_STRING="$CMD_STRING <main classpath in jar>"

nohup $CMD_STRING > $OUTPUT_FILE
```

The output file shows all the jre jar's getting executed, it then loads the jar and throws a class  not found exception for the main class.

I am stumped, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: i'd rather start without all the fancy `nohup` and variable-thingies; first try getting it to run on the cmdline, e.g. `-Xms200m -Xmx200m -XX:MaxPermSize=200m -verbose -cp /Test/app/lib/myjar.jar myjar`. once this works, put it into the script.

Comment: obviously the cmdline should include the java-interpreter itself: `java -Xms200m -Xmx200m -XX:MaxPermSize=200m -verbose -cp /Test/app/lib/myjar.jar myclass` (and `myclass` being your `<main classpath in jar>` - which you haven't given)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the following line:

```
TEST_ROOTDIR = /Test/app
```

I'm certain that upon executing the script, it'd have emitted an error message saying:

```
TEST_ROOTDIR: command not found
```

which you seem to have ignored.  Remove the spaces around `=` while setting the environment variable.  Say:

```
TEST_ROOTDIR=/Test/app
```

Comment: the OP states that "it then loads the jar" which seems to indicate that your assumption is not true; (and actually i tried to undo my downvote (without upvoting))

Comment: Maybe the *assumption* isn't true, but it's a fact that saying `A = foo` won't set the variable `A`!